# VueJS - Dynamically appendChild with v-model attribute to div?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to append an `input` element to the `div#teacherForm` when I press the button, which then runs the function `pushTeacher`.

When the function runs, it appends an `object` to `teachers` arr in `data`. Then it appends two `inputs` with a `v-model` that then refers to the new `two-way bind` object in the `teachers` array.

It does so via this code:

```js
div.innerHTML = `
  <input type="text" placeholder="First name" v-model="this.teachers[${index}].firstName"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" v-model="this.teachers[${index}].lastName"/>
`
```

But, then the two way data binding does not work, I can type as much as I want but it doesn't update `teachers[1].firstName` etc., because the `v-model` looks like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" v-model="this.teachers[1].firstName">
```

Instead of like this (which works) because I set that non-programatically, via the normal way you would write inputs in vue:

```
<input data-v-1586a421="" type="text" placeholder="Teachers' first name">
```

Full code:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loaded">
    <div id="teacherForm">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Teachers' first name"
        v-model="teachers[0].firstName"
        @change="logData"
      />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Teachers' last name" v-model="teachers[0].lastName" />
      <input type="button" value="Push Teacher" @click="pushTeacher()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '../../../../config/config'
const log = console.log

export default {
  name: 'Buttons',
  props: ['loaded'],
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'F2',
      inputIndex: 0,
      teachers: [{ firstName: null, lastName: null }],
      students: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logData() {
      log('teachers' + JSON.stringify(this.teachers))
    },
    pushTeacher() {
      ++this.inputIndex
      let index = this.inputIndex

      // Crete Input and push it..
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = `
          <input type="text" placeholder="First name" v-model="this.teachers[${index}].firstName"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" v-model="this.teachers[${index}].lastName"/>
          `
      document.getElementById('teacherForm').appendChild(div)

      this.teachers.push({ firstName: null, lastName: null })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: it might work try adding this extra attribute in your input section `@input="this.teachers[index].firstName = $this.target.value"` I cannot test the output so it might give you errors also ;)

Comment: Thank you @Haque, I tried what you suggested but couldn't make it work! Though it's solved now anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update current index, so `v-model` update recently added `teacher`.

```html
v-model="teachers[index].firstName"
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      teachers: [
        {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
        },
      ],
      students: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pushTeacher() {
      this.index++

      this.teachers.push({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
      })
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Teachers' first name" v-model="teachers[index].firstName" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Teachers' last name" v-model="teachers[index].lastName" />
      <input type="button" value="Push Teacher" @click="pushTeacher" />
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(teacher, index) in teachers" :key="index">{{ teacher.firstName}} {{ teacher.lastName }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to say I wanted to have an input for each field, but I just realized how stupid that is, your way is miles better and I can always just add a button for removing a teacher. Thank you so much for the answer and improvement of my question Andrew!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use v-for instead.

For example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        text: "Learn JavaScript",
        done: false,
        model: 'javascript'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Learn Vue",
        model: 'reactjs',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        done: true,
        model: 'vue'
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    showValues() {
      console.log(this.todos);
    },
    addField() {
      this.todos.push({
        model: 'test'
      });
      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addField">
    Add Field
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
      <input v-model="todo.model">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button @click="showValues">
    Show Values
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example @pbajr! Changed my mind about the way I was doing it, shouldn't go too manual in Vue lol